# Recreate a layout from Android Design in Action

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

### Update:

I know how to create a listView, and adapt a data source to show up on it. The only thing that I don't have working is my myListItem.xml

---

I'm trying to recreate the list design that is talked about in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dzMHKDkV6U&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8j2B95zGMb8muZvrIy-wcF).

It's an Android Design in Action video and I don't quite understand how they are able to align all of the image in the listItem. I also am not sure of how they create two textViews on top of the other. Do they use a relative layout as the root, or do they nest linear layouts. This is my xml so far, but my images don't grow or shrink (in height) with the content. Can someone please explain it to me?

As you can see... the imageView increases in height depending on the text in the listItem. You can see very clearly that the first and second item in the list are different heights.

Below is a sample picture that they show in the video:

[image]

Here is my xml for my listItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImageView"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/stage_default" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/postImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/postImageView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:text="message text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/postImageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:text="bottom text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its a listview with the custom layout which you need to bind into the `ListView` using adapter.

Comment: I have everything done, and it works, but it doesn't look like the above gui.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't look like above GUI ?

Comment: Do not give the fix height and width to your `ImageView` otherwise it will be always same for any kind of images. Make it  `wrap_content`

Comment: How do they get ALL of the images to stay the same width?

Comment: What do you  want to implement actually ? First you said : `the imageView increases in height depending on the text in the listItem.` and now you want images in same size. If you want the same size images then you have to give fixed size to your imageview as you have already given in your layout i can see.

Comment: Please re-read my question. As you can see, the height of the images change. The width of the images stay the same size. That is what I want to implement.

Comment: Keep height of the imageview `wrap_content` do not fix it so it will adjust image accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out tutorial [ListView with Image and TextView](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) which will guide you for the layout design as well as how to use it.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImageView"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="message text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="bottom text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```